# .htaccess Replace a slash and redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect localhost/_escaped_fragment_=/index to localhost/snapshots/index.html In order to do that I used,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ /$1snapshots$2.html [L,NC,R]
```

But also I need to replace slashes with underscores in $2 and path like localhost/shapshots/products/95.html need to tranform into localhost/shapshots/products_95.html

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want underscores instead of slashes?

Comment: gruntjs make snapshots for ajax sites with underscores instead of slashes

Comment: But is `http://localhost/shapshots_products_95.html` a valid URL? What happens when your open this URL?

Comment: correct way is http://localhost/shapshots/products_95.html - html snapshot of the page with restful way http://localhost/#!/products/95

Comment: Your comment is confusing. Do you want final URL to be: `http://localhost/#!/products/95` now?

Comment: oh ... my bad, you right, I updated. Probably, I need to recreate the thread